# Transcode RTSP for HTML5 Video tag in browser

Tags: javascript, codec, webm, transcode

I have an rtsp stream with MP4 video codec and G711 audio codec. I need to get it work without FlashPlugins.

Video stream in WEB is a frustrating thing.

Is there a possibilty to convert in browser with javascript my Mp4 video and G711 audio in a webm or a h264 codec on fly to use it as a stream for video html5 element or any player!

The problem is, flowplayer does not support rtsp stream, vlc does not work in chrome and flash does not support into android.

so there are many many problems to get it work.
So if there is a possbility to transocde the rtsp stream on the client perhapse there is a possibility to resolve this problems.

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly - MP4 is not a video codec but a container. So the question is the RTSP server really streaming MP4 (which I doubt but it might) or maybe you have confused MP4 with H.264.

Chrome and Firefox both accept live video streams in the fragmented MP4 and WebM (which is irrelevant in this case) video containers. So if you really already have MP4 payload you can simply unpack it from the RTSP stream and forward to the browser. If you have H.264 you will have to perform muxing of the raw H.264 video stream into an MP4 container together with the audio (I am not sure if G711 is supported by browsers, I doubt it so audio might need to be transcoded). The free option is to setup FFmpeg to transcode rtsp to fragmented MP4 (there are lots of examples for this, just Google) or if you are looking for a commercial product our company has just released an video surveillance product that can offer HTML5 compatible live streaming from RTSP cameras. If you have any interest in the commercial product leave a comment.

Comment: Hi, our problem is the browser does not support G711 audio codec and the  gateway where the stream is, is not strong enough to transcode something and in our case we could not add a middleware to do this with ffmpeg or somehting like that. So your video surveillance product does what?

Comment: Since I am all about open source and my main aim is not to advertise our product but to give a helpful answer - maybe you can give some details about the FFmpeg middleware? What do you mean with "could not add" - you simply could not configure FFmpeg or the use of FFmpeg is prohibited? Regarding our product - currently our HTML5 streams have only video tracks (audio is coming in the next few months, we need to decide on the codec etc.), but audio is very close on our roadmap. If you are interested in an evaluation version please contact me at rudolfs.bundulis@luxriot.com

Comment: I included a fallback for flashplayer and we have the intentation to include a webRTC which supports also G711 audio codec so we had to do no transcode or transmux on server side. To explain better our problem, our server is not a real server but an ROUTER on MIPS and 256MB RAM, so we can not trancscode 10 streams on the router. Thx

Comment: @MichaelBurger interresting. As far as I understand from this ( https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=500605 ) H.264 support for webRTC in Chrome is still in development - isn't that a bit of an issue?